# Submitting dropdown form and getting variables (jquery/javascript)

Tags: jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown boxes in one form - only one option can be selected from each box. On pressing the submit button of the form, I want to store the values of the options selected in two different variables.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="form1" method="post">            
    <select id="slt_country" name="country"> 
        <option value="EN" >England</option>
        <option value="SC" >Scotland</option>
        <option value="IR" >Ireland</option>
    </select>

    <select id="slt_zoom" name="zoom"> 
        <option value="IC" >close</option>
        <option value="SC" >far</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" Value="submit" >
</form>
```

And this is what I have come up with so far to retrieve the form:

```
$("#form1").submit (function(){
    var ctry=  $("select#slt_country").val();
    var zm=  $("select#slt_zoom").val();
});
```

I've been struggling for too long now with something that should be so simple, so decided to ask for help.

Comment: I've just tried the above again, and it works...not sure what I was doing wrong before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again.  It should work! ;)